# JQuery AJAX is not sending UTF-8 to my server, only in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, utf-8, internet-explorer-8

I am sending UTF-8, japanese text, to my server.
It works in Firefox.  My access.log and headers are:

```
/ajax/?q=%E6%BC%A2%E5%AD%97
Accept-Charset  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
```

Howeer, in IE8, my access.log says:

```
/ajax/?q=??
```

For some reason, IE8 is turning my AJAX call into question marks.  Why!? I added the scriptCharset and ContentType according to some tutorials, but still no luck.

And this is my code:

```
$.ajax({
    method:"get",
    url:"/ajax/",
    scriptCharset: "utf-8" ,
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
    data:"q="+query ...,
    ...
    })
```

Comment: is the page that initiates the call also utf-8 encoded (with correct charset defined) ?

Comment: Yes, there is the META TAG: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />. Also, accept-charset is in the form.

Comment: Is the page actually saved in UTF-8 format? There was a question with a similar issue the other day that was specifying the UTF-8 charset in the file but the file was saved as ANSI.

Comment: Also, can you confirm 100% there is not a `content-type` header sent by the server, contradicting the meta tag? This can confuse browsers in different ways.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Try encoding the query parameter with `encodeURIComponent()`

```
data:"q="+encodeURIComponent( query )
```

as bobince very correctly noted in his comment, if you use the object notation to pass parameters to the ajax method it will handle the encoding itself..

so

```
data:{ q : query }
```

will make jQuery handle the encoding ..

Comment: +1 This was my first thought, but I thought jQuery handled the encoding.  Now it actually makes sense that jQuery wouldn't handle the encoding if data was already set to a query string. Duh!

Comment: @Andy, I had the same thoughts at start, but then noticed the actual code.. :)

Comment: Yep, this is a good reason to pass a mapping like `{q: query}` into `ajax()` and let jQuery worry about the encoding for you.

Comment: @bobince, +1, very true and i will add this to the answer for future reference.

Comment: oddly enough only encodeURIComponent(query) worked for russian

Comment: @yevgeniy what jQuery version are you using ?

Answer (score 2):

I'we read this post hoping it would solve the problem I had came across and that had to do with utf8 conversions.

In my case it turned out that the server engine (node.js) calculating the Content-length of the data with the data considered to be raw and not utf8, thus two character extended chars in uft8 was calculated as if they where one char resulting in the server sending one character too little.

See what I did to solve it here: [Not well formed Json when sending to CouchDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13915915/not-well-formed-json-when-sending-to-couchdb/13915917#13915917)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but I had this problem recently and I'd like to contribute just in case someone else has the same problem.
I'm using PHP but I'm sure there's an option on every serverside language. It was just a couple of things:

1. Make sure you're sending the right headers on your ajax response by adding header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); This must be your first line. If you have any errors saying that headers have been sent already or something like that is because somewhere in your code you are outputing an extra space or something before sending the header so check your code.
2. When you build your response in your server, make sure you convert all your chars to the correspondig HTML char using echo htmlentities($your-string, null, 'utf-8); Because even after telling IE that you are sending utf-8 data, it seems like IE forgets that or it doesn't simply assume anything so adding this to your code will ensure the right output.

Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use `encodeURIComponent()` in javaScript. Here is the sample:

```
function doPost()
{
    var URL = "http://localhost/check.php?yab=" + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("formSearch").childNodes[1].value);
    xmlHttp.open("GET", URL);
    xmlHttp.send();
};
```