# jQuery ajax array to json

Tags: php, jquery, json, object

If I want to send an array from PHP to JavaScript, I do something like this with PHP:

```
<?php
    $json=array();
    $json['datetime']="Something";
    $json['timestamp']="Something else"
    $encoded=json_encode($json);
    die($encoded);
?>
```

And this on jQuery/JavaScript (using Ajax):

```
...
success: function(response){
var chat = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
datetime=chat['datetime'];
timestamp=chat['timestamp'];
...
```

I was about wondering about doing the opposite.

In jQuery i have this array:

```
data_send['username']=$(".chat_username").val();
data_send['message']=$(".chat_message").val();
```

I want to encode this array as a JSON object, send this object via Ajax, and then take this object from $_POST/$_GET and decode it to an array.

How can I do this?

Comment: you want to send data from the client to the server like [.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)?

Comment: @ChrisPappas why?  There's a standard format for sending key-value pairs to CGI scripts, and it's _not_ JSON!

Comment: @Alnitak now i use something like `data: "name="+escape($(".chat_username").val())+"&message="+escape($(".chat_text").val()),` this doesn't work for special characters, and greek characters (utf-8 encoding)

Comment: @Chris because you should be using a map, not a string - see my answer.

Comment: @ChrisPappas also check http://stackoverflow.com/a/2473382/1114171 if you still having problems basically suggests using [encodeURIComponent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp)

Comment: @Alnitak thanks, can't see how I missed that in such a small paragraph lol, I have removed the comment as it is misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to encode an array into JSON from Javascript you can use `JSON.stringify(myarray)`.

However, you shouldn't do that to send it to a PHP script.

jQuery has built in support for passing a map of key-value pairs in a POST method - just pass it as the `data` parameter in `$.ajax()` or as the second parameter to `$.post()`.

jQuery will then correctly URI encode any unsafe characters that appear (whether in keys, or values), so in your case you can use:

```
var data_send = {
     username: $(".chat_username").val(),
     message:  $(".chat_message").val()
};
$.post(url, data_send, success_handler);

// or $.ajax({url: url, data: data_send, ... });
```

PHP then has built in support for *reading* that map - it's `$_POST`:

```
<?php
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $message  = $_POST['message'];
?>
```

Comment: Then in php `$data_send=json_decode($_POST['data_send']);$username=$data_send['username'];` Am i right?

Comment: @ChrisPappas no - you don't need to JSON encode it or decode it at all - that's the whole point of my answer.  I've updated it with an example.

Comment: `<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: username in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\apps\chat\chat_write.php</b> on line <b>2</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: message in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\apps\chat\chat_write.php</b> on line <b>4</b><br />`

Comment: @ChrisPappas NB I've updated the sample code to make it cleaner - the original just copied a snippet from your own code which on its own was incomplete.

Comment: @ChrisPappas right - as expected you've made `data_send` an array, it should really be an object, per my updated code above.

Comment: your codes works..the insertion into my database is correct..
`$_POST['username']` doesn't have problem but `$_POST['message']` has..
The chat updates correctly (i see a new row with the correct username), but no message displayed

Comment: $(".chat_text")..
THx u so much!!

Comment: @Chris it does help if your HTML and JS are self-consistent ;-)