# Post a UTF-8 string to a servlet using jquery

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

I'm trying to POSt a UTF-8 string to my servlet (hosted in TomCat) but the string read on the server side is not UTF-8.  I've verified via firebug that the ajax header's content-type has the utf-8 encoding set. I'm posting "MÉXICO" to the server but I'm receiving "MÃ‰XICO".

```
$.ajaxSetup({ 
    scriptCharset: "utf-8" , 
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
});


$.ajax({
  url: "SetData",
  type: 'POST',
  data: 'MÉXICO',
  success: function(){
      console.log('Data set');
  }
});
```

Here's the java code in the servlet

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( request, "UTF-8" ) );        
char[] chr = new char[5];
reader.read( chr );
builder.append( chr );
```

**UPDATE 1**

I changed the posting data in js to encodeURIComponent('MÉXICO') but the server still reads "MÃ‰XICO".

But, if I get the string value of encodeURIComponent('MÉXICO') i.e. 'M%C3%89XICO' it works!
I'm zapped! Any idea why this should work?

```
$.ajax({
  url: "SetData",
  type: 'POST',
  //data: 'MÉXICO', ** does not work
  //data: encodeURIComponent('MÉXICO'),  ** does not work
  data: 'M%C3%89XICO',  //works !!!!
  success: function(){
      console.log('Data set');
  }
})
```

;

Comment: Finally, figured out why is was not woking when the string was not hardcoded. I hadn't set the charecter encodin of the document! Thanks evenyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what are you doing and what kind of request parameter are you sending. Shouldnt code be something like that:

```
...
data:{key:'MÉXICO'},
...
```

OR

```
...
data:{key:encodeURIComponent('MÉXICO')},
...
```

AND in servlet

```
...
request.getParameter('key')
...
```

OR

```
 stringURLDecoder.decode(
                             request.getParameter('key').toString(),
                             'UTF-8'
                        );
```

**Or I didn't understand anything (If this is the case sorry :/)**

Comment: +1 even if this doesn't resolve what the OP asked, it is important to note that you need to send data in the format that you specified.  In this case he said it would be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: I just tried both your suggestionns  and they didn't work. I still get MÃ‰XICO on the server. Thanks anyway!

Comment: DMoses: what should i change the contentType to?

Comment: It's fine as is if you always plan on encoding it.

Comment: Sorry I think I'm going down the wrong path by explaining the byte encoding at a protocol instead of keeping it all in the application space.  I should have followed the rules of encapsulation.  I deleted my answer as it pertains to the protocol level which would be important in a web service enviornment.

Comment: DMoses, any idea why posting with the hardcoded encoded string works but calling via encodeURIComponent doesnt?

Answer (score 1):

Try encoding data value with encodeURIComponent()

```
data: encodeURIComponent('MÉXICO')
```

Source: [JQuery AJAX is not sending UTF-8 to my server, only in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473316/jquery-ajax-is-not-sending-utf-8-to-my-server-only-in-ie)

Comment: He's using POST.  So I don't think that pertains to him.

Comment: no luck! I even change the servlet code to decode the stringURLDecoder.decode( builder.toString(), "UTF-8" );

Comment: Maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/607176/java-equivalent-to-javascripts-encodeuricomponent-that-produces-identical-outpu